# Adapting Strftime for PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I have what I hope is a very quick question for an error that occurred as I pushed my code up to production. 
In development I use SQLite and everything works fine, but as I push to production and use PostgreSQL I get errors in my code.

From the logs it appears to be from how I convert my date inputs in my database to suit my lazyhighcharts code:

In SQLite this code works perfectly:

```
# Convert date to javascript format to work with Highcharts
for i in 0..@data_sorted.length-1
  @data_sorted[i][0] = @data_sorted[i][0].strftime('%F')
  @data_sorted[i][0] = Time.parse(@data_sorted[i][0]).utc.to_i*1000
end
```

However I get: "NoMethodError (undefined method `strftime' for 2017:Fixnum):"

What is the best way to adapt this code to work with PostgreSQL?

I have also tried this method:

```
# Convert date to javascript format to work with Highcharts
for i in 0..@data_sorted.length-1
  @data_sorted[i][0] = @data_sorted[i][0].to_s
  @data_sorted[i][0] = Time.parse(@data_sorted[i][0]).utc.to_i*1000
end
```

and again it works in SQLite but get the following error: ArgumentError (argument out of range):

Create action code:

```
def create


@user = User.find( params[:user_id] )

@saving = @user.saving.build( saving_params )

respond_to do |format|
if @saving.save
 format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Saving was successfully    created.' }
 format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @saving }
else
 format.html { render :new }
 format.json { render json: @saving.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
end
```

Comment: `However I get undefined method "strftime" when I push this to production...` this is a verbal description of the error message... can you actually copy/paste the real error message straight from your logs? (usually Rails will tell you what kind of object the undefined method is undefined on eg `nil`, which helps you figure out what is actually going wrong).

Comment: sorry I was being lazy here is the error: NoMethodError (undefined method `strftime' for 2017:Fixnum):

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a Postgres problem at all. `strftime` is a method called on Date/Time/DateTime classes, but your error messages says you're calling it on a Fixnum (2017). Are you sure `@data_sorted[i][0]` is returning a Time object?

Comment: The reason I believe it is a pg issue is that it all works perfectly fine in development mode, the only difference between the two modes is my database type? The data_sorted comes from the database using these lines of code:

`data = Saving.where(user_id: params[:user_id]).pluck(:week,:amount)`
`@data_sorted = data.sort {|x,y| x[0] <=> y[0] }`

Comment: `:week` is a `:date` object in the database by the way, that is entered via a date form field

Comment: `2017` is the year, not a week... so something odd is happening there... can you console into production and check out what you get if you run `data = Saving.where(user_id: params[:user_id]).pluck(:week,:amount)` there (as opposed to what you get on dev)?

Comment: Are you sure every single row in `Savings` in prod has a full date stored in `week`? The error very clearly states you're calling `strftime` on a Fixnum.

Comment: On a side note (and much more importantly) it's bad practice to have different databases for your different environments, exactly so this problem never arises. Postgres is heaps easy to install, I'd recommend migrating over to that in development

Comment: I have updated the original post with the create action - I am a little unfamiliar with working with pg but will run my db the same in the future.

Is there something unique to pg in saving dates to the db? it seems to automatically rounding to simply the year for some reason

Comment: Impossible to tell what is going amiss with just that controller code. Mainly, what is actually in `saving_params`? Maybe the save is going awry, maybe your view isn't passing the parameters in correctly. I'd suggest using some debugger (like [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry#runtime-invocation)) to see what is going on

Comment: It was a problem with my view using a stftime to pre fill the value of the date box, once I removed the `:value => stftime (...)` from the form it all worked fine. not too sure why this didn't show up in development mode though...

Comment: Thank you for your help, you helped push to where the bug really was as I was convinved it was my controller haha.

Comment: No worries mate! Glad we could help